# What does upgrading Pyromancy Flame do?

Tags: dark-souls

The main casting weapon for pyromancy is Pyromancy Flame. It looks like a fiery hand in the inventory. You can upgrade it at Firelink Shrine later in the game. But what does upgrading it actually do? Does it boost all pyromancy skills damage or duration?

Comment: Whoops, I originally answered this as if it were being asked for Dark Souls 2. Since I'm not positive that things are the exactly the same in DS1, someone else can feel free to answer instead.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading a Pyromancy Glove increases the MagAdjust of the glove, which in turn increases the damage of most direct attack pyromancies. In most cases, it has no effect on status buff pyromancies such as Power Within or Flash Sweat.

Being that Pyromancy does not rely at all on Soul Level, only on purchased glove, it is a go to weapon for playthroughs looking to keep their level at a minimum.

Comment: This is correct. I would add that upgrading it is a very easy way to enable yourself to deal very high damage via spells, without requiring an investment into Intelligence or Faith.